Error 500 en wsdl de la Dian "An error occurred when verifying security for the message."
Estoy tratando de enviar el mensaje SOAP firmado con el mismo certificado con el que se firman las facturas, pero el WebService de la DIAN genera un error, estoy trabajando en c#, realiza la prueba en SoapUI y la petición es exitosa pero en c# me genera el error:

Error 500 en wsdl de la Dian "An error occurred when verifying
security for the message."

Ya verifique el soap firmado en soapUI y lo tengo igual que en mi código en c#, alguien sabe porque me sale ese error?
Mensaje SOAP:
<soap:Envelope xmlns:wcf="http://wcf.dian.colombia" xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">


<soap:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">


<wsse:Security xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">


<wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-3ee38a30-5589-400b-98b4-680ce06a15b4">

<wsu:Created>2024-10-28T19:17:49Z</wsu:Created>

<wsu:Expires>2024-10-28T19:22:49Z</wsu:Expires>

</wsu:Timestamp>

<wsse:BinarySecurityToken wsu:Id="X509-e5ad96fe-7147-445f-854f-acf1e843d6ad" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">MIII...... </wsse:BinarySecurityToken>


<ds:Signature Id="SIG-987ac696-5636-4973-b577-3e1a5e00907f" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">


<ds:SignedInfo>


<ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">

<ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="wsa soap wcf"/>

</ds:CanonicalizationMethod>

<ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xml-dsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>


<ds:Reference URI="#id-f9bf8736-a590-495c-9df2-895b25551aa7">


<ds:Transforms>


<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">

<ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="soap wcf"/>

</ds:Transform>

</ds:Transforms>

<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>

<ds:DigestValue>QdaLmY8mJm1Eaw1Wvuj1TMF1NuJdrBoqYduYS/dxwLo=</ds:DigestValue>

</ds:Reference>

</ds:SignedInfo>

<ds:SignatureValue>HnspSKnwpcqZSR97F7OnKP1Q+Z/3VNMx9SxvpVvxRNTuBW67tLSWT6lJSxDmT6aGNrQbNE+m7lJP0eSGPk7xB98AdmQNUs9uPuJJ7PBgQVwDZWFTSBLfQqELqS3Lq93jyoxZ0nFbVtxDSjq5Fp4W373nK1kL/fwsXzPvDamToOgOYGxMoPfUj7bUddJXaA9ZMSzWFNuBgpWfAhrAJO6eDSbY/z9orKwj6vfcAfNdw5Tt3YrN6KIpRoAJ4sq6vYYiQzCx5E7yB5dGVwmqjink+vW89lpS/N63wFFj/eexi5U95ozbB8eIJRlJIhO6UQiyNdvynkuknqFE7p6XBgL8vw==</ds:SignatureValue>


<ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-eb51d405-2f23-4311-b1db-1c9ef67932a2">


<ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-eb51d405-2f23-4311-b1db-1c9ef67932a2">


<wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-594dfa2c-a1b5-45f3-aace-f45fe65d0165">

<wsse:Reference ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" URI="#X509-e5ad96fe-7147-445f-854f-acf1e843d6ad"/>

</wsse:SecurityTokenReference>

</ds:KeyInfo>

</ds:Signature>

</wsse:Security>

<wsa:Action>http://wcf.dian.colombia/IWcfDianCustomerServices/GetNumberingRange</wsa:Action>

<wsa:To xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="ID-id-f9bf8736-a590-495c-9df2-895b25551aa7">https://vpfe-hab.dian.gov.co/WcfDianCustomerServices.svc </wsa:To>

</soap:Header>


<soap:Body>


<wcf:GetNumberingRange>

<wcf:accountCode>{1}</wcf:accountCode>

<wcf:accountCodeT>{2}</wcf:accountCodeT>

<wcf:softwareCode>{3}</wcf:softwareCode>

</wcf:GetNumberingRange>

</soap:Body>

</soap:Envelope>


El xml es generado manualmente o automaticamente (con la herramienta de servicios) ???

@Yussef lo genere manualmente, pero generando correctamnete los valores del digestvalue y signaturevalue, debo generarlo con alguna herramienta de servicios en c#?

Era bastante común que la herramienta automática genere un xml incompatible (sobre todo con ws hechos en java) de ahí que preguntaba, pero no es tu caso ya que lo generas manualmente. Por mi parte, no tengo idea de que puede estar provocando el error

@Yussef tambien lo genere automaticamente con svcutil.exe y me genera el mismo error:  An error occurred when verifying security for the message.
manual y automaticamente siempre es el mismo error, pero con SOAPUI no me genera este error y hace la petición correctamente.

Verifica también las fechas del computador, no puede tener más de 3 minutos de diferencia con la hora oficial.
